# Rewrite-mod - redirecting to root folder inside of the root folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite-module

I use `.htaccess` to redirect all the requests to the `root` folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) root/$1 [L]
```

So when someone puts in the search bar `example.com/test.html` they go to `root/test.html` but the problem here is that when user puts in the search bar `example.com/root` they get redirected to `root/` not `root/root/`

Comment: When I test that rule it shows as `root/root/` for me...

Comment: @Lag does you .htaccess file look the same as mine? or is their something am missing

Comment: That depends on whether you have other rules in your `.htaccess` or not. My test was off of the rule you posted above.

Comment: What you have shown should not work at all ... it should cause an endless redirect, because once you have rewritten the original request to `root/test.html`, that is again matched by `(.*)`, so would get rewritten to `root/root/test.html`, and so on ...

Comment: @CBroe i forgot to say in the root folder theres another .htaccess file contains `ReWriteRule (.*) $1 [L]`

Comment: That's the problem here. Your other htaccess is interfaring with this. You need to remover one of the files ( the folder htaccess) and keep your rules in root